# How to update Svelte writable store values with input tag

Tags: object, input, svelte

I have a writable store in Svelte with an object. I'd like to display the properties and be able to change the property values as a user.

I'm able to get the properties and values to display in input tags with an on:input event to update the value in the store, but I get an error saying the sampleStore.set isn't a function. I tried to add a custom update function to the store, but I'm getting the same error.

What's the best way to do this?

Sample code below

Store.js

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

function createSampleStore() {
  const sampleStore = writable({
    property1a: 'value1a',
    property1b: 'value1b',
    etc...
  }

  return {
    subscribe: sampleStore.subscribe,
    updateValue: (propertyName, propertyValue) =>
      sampleStore.update((o) => {
        o[propertyName] = propertyValue;
        return o;
      }),
  };
}

export const sampleStore = createSampleStore();
```

InfoDisplay.svelte

```
<script>
  import {sampleStore} from './sampleStore.js';

  const propertyNames = Object.keys($sampleStore);
  $: console.log($sampleStore);
</script>

<ul>
  {#each propertyNames as propertyName}
    <li>
      {propertyName}:
        <input
          on:input={(value) =>
           sampleStore.updateValue(propertyName, propertyValue)}
           bind:value={$sampleStore[propertyName]}
        />
    </li>
  {/each}
</ul>
```

I tried to adjust the values shown in the input tag and have the values in the store be updated, but I kept getting the .set is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding on the input `value` creates a get/set relationship, you should only pass the value in and use the event to get it out:

```html
<input
  on:input={e => sampleStore.updateValue(propertyName, e.target.value)}
  value={$sampleStore[propertyName]} /> <!-- no bind here -->
```

You also do not need a custom store to do this and could just use a `writable` directly:

```html
<input bind:value={$store[propertyName]} />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/54c7a8b9b48e41e589939c30e9c79cf2?version=3.55.1)

Comment: Thank you! I was overthinking it with the custom store